# 401 when issuing a WebClient request in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm hoping someone can help me with this as I am at my wits' end.

I have a simple Web API web service that checks for the existence of a workspace on our document management system to determine security access.

When I run this service in the browser it works fine.  However when I try to use the service in another Web API application it gives a 401.

I've tried pretty much everything I can think of and can find on here.  It is using Windows Authentication and no matter what I try, NTLM, Negotiate or Negotiate:Kerberos, the credentials of the current user are not passed through.  If I hard code my userid, password and domain however it works.  The code is below

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Session/CheckSecurity")]
    public HttpResponseMessage CheckSecurity(string id)
    {
        WebClient client;
        WindowsIdentity userId;
        string result;

        try
        {
            userId = (WindowsIdentity)User.Identity;

            using (WindowsImpersonationContext context = userId.Impersonate())
            {
                client = new System.Net.WebClient() { UseDefaultCredentials = true }; 
                client.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/json");
                result = client.DownloadString(new Uri(String.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Url"], id)));
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
        }
        catch (WebException webExcp)
        {
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)webExcp.Response;
            resp.Headers.Remove("WWW-Authenticate");
            // return 403 instead of 401 to prevent security pop up
            return new HttpResponseMessage(resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized ? HttpStatusCode.Forbidden : resp.StatusCode);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You create the `context` object but don't use it in the `WebClient`, is that intentional?

Comment: My understanding is that the context triggers the impersonation of the requesting user rather than the App Pool user and that UseDefaultCredentials would pick this up.  If that's wrong then how would I go about using the context in the WebRequest call?

Answer (score 1):

So after 2 days of trying everything I could think of and tearing my hair out a Google search led me to a completely unrelated issue where using a proxy can cause authentication problems.

This triggered an aha! moment and I turned off Fiddler.  Lo and behold everything worked as it was supposed to!

I'm not sure why this happens but I'll have a play with Fiddler to see if I can stop this happening in the future.